# Printing a “triangle” of asterisks, in c++

Tags: c++, geometry

i want to make a generic code that prints such output, mean user can  enter any value +whole.

```
    *
   * *
  * * *
 * * * *
* * * * *
```

for 5

and

```
  *
 * *
* * *
```

for 3.

here what i make. but it prints just right triangle. Any helps. thanks in advance.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
int val;

cout << "Enter the number: ";
cin >> val;

int t  = val;
int x = val;

for(int r = 1; r <= val; r++)
{


for(int c  = 1; c <=t ; c++)
{
    if(c < x)
    {
    cout << ' ';
    }
    else
    {
    cout << "*";
    }
}    
cout << endl;
x = x-1;
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is homework, right?  Think about what you've been asked to do and how to break it down into pieces.  It will probably help you the most to take some graph paper and draw some triangles by filling in squares and seeing what the relationship is between filled in and non-filled in spaces.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

place 'space' after * in cout, it adjust all your sequence. mean cout << "* "; thats it.

Comment: You could be really pedantic and use `"*\n"` for the `c == t` case, but this is probably correct enough for homework